# Hide/Undo list using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a notification list using angular js. I have a drop down on the right side of each notification list where I can hide notification and undo hidden notifications. I am assigning the id to each notification list using ***ng-attr-id*** and adding a class to it to hide the same. it works fine, however when I refresh the page the hidden notification show up. how can I prevent this?
Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
 <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="notification in notificationList" ng-attr-id="{{ 'notification-list-' + $index }}">
     <div class="md-list-item-text">
           <div class="notification-content">
              <div class="ng-flex-box">
                 <label class="notification-header label" data-ng-bind="notification.content"></label>
              </div>
              <label class="notification-message" data-ng-bind="notification.applicationId"></label>
              <label class="notification-category" data-ng-bind="notification.category"></label>
              <div>
                 <span class="notification-date pull-right" data-ng-bind="notification.date"></span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <md-menu>
              <i class="icon  icon-sm icon-tree_open" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <md-menu-content class="hide-notification-content">
                 <md-menu-item>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$ctrl.hideNotification($index)">Hide this notification</a>
                 </md-menu-item>
                 <md-menu-item>
                    <a href="#">Manage notification from this app</a>
                 </md-menu-item>
              </md-menu-content>
           </md-menu>
     </div>
  </md-list-item>
```

**JS**

```
  $ctrl.hideNotification = function (id) {
               $ctrl.notificationListId= id;
               angular.element('#notification-list-'+$ctrl.notificationListId).addClass('hide-notification-class');            
            }
```

**CSS**

```
    .hide-notification-class{
         display: none;   
    }
```

Comment: Initially when u load the page the notification should be hidden ?  Why not just add class `hide-notification-class` to the element , then later u click button to show it .

Comment: no. Initially i need to show all the notification. user should be able to hide it on click based on their preferences @cjmling

Comment: So when user click hide, then later user reload the page, it should be hidden by default now ?

Comment: Yes exactly. i would like to display a "undo" button later on in place of the hidden notification on reload

Comment: have you tried using localstorage ? it's simple ... you can use: localstorage.setItem(ID + "_HIDDEN", true);

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a user reload the page all the angular $scope values get reset.

You have to store the user preference somewhere either as browser cookies or store on backend server database.

Then when user load the page you get this stored preference and show/hide it by default based on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

First using cookies/localstorage - `localStorage` is simple `setItem(key, value)`, `getItem(key)`

For example:

```
localStorage.setItem(ID + "_ISHIDDEN", true);
```

and cookies are [documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

The other choice is to use a server-side database, you can load the hidden list of each user or add a column to your current table: boolean HIDDEN then retrieve it and change the hidden/shown state of each notification

Answer (score 0):

Try this format.

**JAVASCRIPT**

> $scope.isCollapsed = true;

**HTML**

> ```
> <md-button ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"> Show/hide </md-button>
>
> <collapsible-content ng-show='isCollapsed'>
>    Content
> </collapsible-content>
> ```

Use JavaScript **localStorage** option to save ***isCollapsed*** value and load it when the page is refreshed.